# Foreign key references using Java

Tags: java, sql, database, constraints

I am having some trouble getting my foreign keys to match up with some of my primary keys. I keep getting the error `"Error: Cannot add foreign key constraint"`. I don't know what I'm doing wrong but it might be because I have been staring at it for too long. Any suggestions?

```
//customer table
        statement.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.Customers ("
                + "  FirstName VARCHAR(21) NOT NULL, "
                + "  StreetAddress VARCHAR(45) NULL, "
                + "  TelephoneNumber VARCHAR(45) NULL, "
                + "  SetOfFrequentFlyerMemberships VARCHAR(45) NULL, "
                + "  PreferredPaymentMethod VARCHAR(45) NULL, "
                + "  Preferences VARCHAR(45) NULL, "
                + "  City VARCHAR(45) NULL, "
                + "  State INT NULL, "
                + "  LastName VARCHAR(45) NULL, "
                + "  CustomerID VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, "
                + "  Customerscol VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, "
                + "  PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID, Preferences))");

        //reservation table
        statement.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.Reservations ( "
                + "  CustomerID INT NOT NULL, "
                + "  TravelAgent VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, "
                + "  FlightID INT NULL, "
                + "  PaymentType VARCHAR(45) NULL, "
                + "  StatusOfReservation VARCHAR(45) NULL, "
                + "  ReservationID VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, "
                + "  PaymentID INT NOT NULL, "
                + "  Preferences VARCHAR(45) NULL, "
                + "  PRIMARY KEY (ReservationID), "
                + "  CONSTRAINT fk_Reservations_Customers1 "
                + "  FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) "
                + "  REFERENCES mydb.Customers(CustomerID), "
                + "  CONSTRAINT fk_Reservations_Payment1 "
                + "  FOREIGN KEY (PaymentID) "
                + "  REFERENCES mydb.Payment(PaymentID), "
                + "  CONSTRAINT fk_Reservations_Flights1 "
                + "  FOREIGN KEY (FlightID) "
                + "  REFERENCES mydb.Flights(FlightID), "
                + "  CONSTRAINT fk_Reservations_Preference1 "
                + "  FOREIGN KEY (Preferences) "
                + "  REFERENCES mydb.Customers(Preferences))");

            //frequent flyer membership
            statement.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.FrequentFlyerMemberships ( "
                + "  FrequentFlyerID INT NOT NULL, "
                + "  customerID VARCHAR(45) NULL, "
                + "  ReservationID VARCHAR(45) NULL, "
                + "  PRIMARY KEY (FrequentFlyerID), "
                + "  CONSTRAINT fk_FrequentFlyerMemberships_Reservations1 "
                + "  FOREIGN KEY (ReservationID) "
                + "  REFERENCES mydb.Reservations(ReservationID))");
```

This isn't all of my code but these are the only blocks that I seem to be having problems with.

Comment: Where are  `mydb.Flights` ,'mydb.Payment' tables

Comment: I'm **very** worried about a table called `Customers` where `Preferences` is part of the primary key.  There's no reason for it to be a part of _any_ key.  Given your current column list, it should most likely be _only_ `CustomerId`.  That column should likely be a plain `INTEGER` (I can't see any reason for a 45 character string as an id here).

Answer (score 3):

use like the below script for making foreign key to composite key of other table
This will work

```
CONSTRAINT fk_Reservations_Customers1   
FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID,Preferences)   
REFERENCES stackoverflowprob.Customers(CustomerID,Preferences));
```